# Is natbib included in TeX Live?

Tags: texlive, natbib

I'm extremely new at this. Basically I'm a would-be academic who needs (and therefore wants) to use LaTeX for my professional writing stuffs. This means that the most important thing to me is to be able to get a decent bibliography sorted.

I've been having trouble installing `natbib` (which I apparently need) so I heard that TeXLive comes with `natbib` built in. Can anyone tell me whether this is right? And if so, does this mean that it's already set up to use the `natbib` commands?

Many thanks and sorry if this is embarrassingly basic.

Comment: Don't use natbib. Use the package biblatex together with biber. Both is in a current texlive.

Comment: @Ulrike does the various journals accept biblatex?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Note that you don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: As Ulrike said, you might want to change your choice, so I'd recommend reading this [post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25701/bibtex-vs-biber-and-biblatex-vs-natbib).

Comment: I have no idea, but if they want to compile the file themselves you can't be sure that natbib can be used either. In such cases you probably will have to adapt your document to their needs anyway. But biblatex is the most flexible and powerful system available today so you should use it unless someone force you to use something else.

Comment: Yes, `natbib` is still pretty standard despite the newer alternatives. The [ctan page for natbib](http://ctan.org/pkg/natbib) indicates that it is contained in both TeXLive and MiKTeX.

Answer (score 6):

The `natbib` package has been around for many years on CTAN and has a 'free' license, so like many other such packages is available as part of TeX Live. Many 'academic' bibliography styles are also available for `natbib`, which is therefore required for submission using some journal/publisher templates. As such, it's widely available and supported.

As is mentioned in comments, the [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) package offers a more 'complete' approach to bibliographies, and if you have a 'free hand' you should consider using it rather than `natbib`. However, this will depend on your academic discipline and likely work-flow, which we'd need details of to give a more accurate answer on this part.